# How to expand and collapse only the first item in accordion using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here's what I've tried doing

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const Accordion = ({ items }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    setDisplay(display === "active" ? "" : "active");
  };

  const renderedItems = items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Fragment key={item.title}>
        <div className={`${display} title`} onClick={() => handleChange(index)}>
          <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
          {item.title}
        </div>
        <div className={`${display} content`}>
          <p>{item.content}</p>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="ui styled accordion">
      {renderedItems}
      {activeIndex}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

But on clicking a single item, it expands or collapses all others. Also, I want only one expanded item at any given time, so if a user clicks another item the previous one should close automatically.

Here is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Accordion from "./components/Accordion";

const items = [
  {
    title: "What is React?",
    content: "React is a front end javascript library",
  },
  {
    title: "What is Angular?",
    content: "Angular is a front end javascript framework",
  },
  {
    title: "What is Vue?",
    content: "Vue is a front end javascript library",
  },
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion items={items} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your issue :

```
// Means if display is active so nothing else it's active, so everything is active
setDisplay(display === "active" ? "" : "active");
```

The display variable is shared between each accordion bodies... Always the same

Do you really need an `display` var ?

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const Accordion = ({ items }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = index => {
    setActiveIndex(activeIndex === index ? null : index);
  };

  const renderedItems = items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Fragment key={item.title}>
        <div className={`${display} title`} onClick={() => handleChange(index)}>
          <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
          {item.title}
        </div>
        <div className={`${activeIndex === index ? 'active' : ''} content`}>
          <p>{item.content}</p>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="ui styled accordion">
      {renderedItems}
      {activeIndex}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I really appreciate it. I don't need display var, I was just figuring out a way to achieve the functionality. 

Your code works but I also wanted to close the accordion item on clicking it again which is not happening. Can you help me with that?

Right now with the code, it's closing the accordion item when I choose another item. If I choose the same item(opened item) again it should close it.

Thank you.

Comment: @SamarthMehrotra you're welcome, look at the handleClick function

Comment: Ohh my god I'm so sorry I forgot to add code setActiveIndex inside handleChange. 
Thanks a lot, you're a lifesaver.